# Passing "global" and "ignore" options to browserify via the command line

Tags: browserify, node-modules, babeljs, babelify

I'm using browserify with babelify to transpile a JS file. The JS file `require()`s a component in `node_modules`, which I also want transpiled.

As per the [FAQ on babelify's GitHub](https://github.com/babel/babelify), to achieve this I should be using the `global` and `ignore` options to specify which folder in `node_modules` should also be transpiled:

```
browserify().transform("babelify", {
  global: true,
  ignore: /\/node_modules\/(?!app\/)/
});
```

I'm using `browserify` via the command line and I can't figure out how to pass those options in. I'm also getting confused at whether these are options specific to `browserify` or `babelify`.

Here's the command I'm running:

```
browserify -t [ babelify ] input.js > output.js
```

Here's my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [ "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": "defaults, ie >= 11"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread" ]
}
```

I can't find `global` documented anywhere in [`browserify`'s options](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#btransformtr-opts) even though the `babelify` README mentions it. I tried `--global-transform` and gave it the module name I want transpiled (fluent), but got `Unexpected object exported by the fluent package. Expected a transform function.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that normal regexes are not possible on the command line.

But you can get creative and use the inverse `only`:

```sh
browserify -t [ babelify --global --only [ your-main-js-directory node_modules\/app ] --presets [ @babel/preset-env ] ] input.js > output.js
```

You can specify more packages like this:

```sh
--only [ your-main-js-directory node_modules\/app node_modules\/another-app ]
```